# PHP Default String Encoding

Tags: php

Could someone explain why the output is `ASCII` in the last three tests below?

I get the same results on my own system, [PHPTester.net](http://phptester.net/), and [PhpFiddle.org](http://phpfiddle.org/).

```
echo mb_internal_encoding();                       // UTF-8

$str = 'foobar';
echo mb_check_encoding($str, 'UTF-8');             // true
echo mb_detect_encoding($str);                     // ASCII

$encoded = utf8_encode($str);
echo mb_detect_encoding($encoded);                 // ASCII

$converted = mb_convert_encoding($str, 'UTF-8');
echo mb_detect_encoding($converted);               // ASCII
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That would be because there are no characters in `foobar` that cannot be represented in ASCII.

`mb_check_encoding($str, 'UTF-8')` works because ASCII text is innately compatible with UTF-8 (deliberately so)

But in the absence of multi-byte characters, there's no discernible difference between the two. Proof of this: `'foobar' === utf8_encode('foobar') // true`